# Running servlet program

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have recently installed Tomcat 6.0.29 on my Ubuntu 10.04 system. Process till the localhost connectivity is fine but when I tried to run a simple hello program, it giving me the following error:

> type Status report
>
> message
>   /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorldExample
>
> description The requested resource
>   (/opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorldExample)
>   is not available.

I have tried to reinstall tomcat by the different methods give on other sites but the result is same. I am not yet sure where I am going wrong. Please can anyone describe me the correct method of running a servlet program ie, where to store the actual Java and class files.

Comment: can you please post error log?

Comment: have you set up the definitions in web.xml http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html

Answer (score 0):

- Have you got a correct `web.xml` file? It needs `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` tags.
- Check that WAR file from which you deployed your web-app is not corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

always put you class in package, eg, not `HelloWorldExample`, but `foo.HelloWorldExample`.
Tomcat (and other containers as well) doesn't like default packages.